# Joomla template width resize

Tags: joomla2.5

Hi I would like to know how to change the template width of a Joomla 2.5 template.

I am facing problem like below.

in different sizes of Monitor (Desktop or Laptop - 15",17",19") - I am getting different blank spaces on both left and right side of the template.

Is that possible to reduce the template width ?

Answer (score 0):

The width of the page is determined by CSS styling so start by using something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to examine the page and figure out what rule governs the page width. For example there might be a container div that wraps around all the page content, and its width is set at 960px.

Firepage will also tell you the location of the CSS file, for example it might be in templates/template-name/css/theme.css

Sign-in to the backend of your site, then extensions > template manager . In the template manager : styles view, go to the entry for your template and click the link in the right hand column and you will find links to all the css files for your theme. Open the CSS file you located earlier (eg theme.css) and add an over-riding rule. For example

```
.container{  
width:900px;
}
```

Naturally the normal CSS rules apply here, so you want your new rule to be after the original.

If your theme is responsive, you may have to repeat this process at different window sizes or viewports, and create additional over-riding rules inside @media requests. You will need to figure that out yourself or post a URL.

Good luck